# 2-way ANOVA interaction between a factor with itself, does not make sense?

Tags: anova, manova, jmp

I have done a DOE that I am in the process of analyze with a two-way ANOVA.

The DOE has been generated by the JMP software and I specified that **I want calculate the main effects and the 2nd interactions between factors**. I did not need to specify how the DOE is generated (using JMP standard settings).
*Edit* Factors are set as numerical

When calculating the 2-way ANOVA I specify that I want the main effects + the 2nd interactions (in JMP using standard settings). This gives me that factors can interact with themselves (See example below). For me this makes no sense since a factor can not interact with itself?

Here is an example of what the result for SumofSquare (SS) looks like with two factors (apple and pear), each at three levels.

The experiment is about how much **apple** or **pears** to add to a fruit salad with the levels low=1,middle=2 or high=3

Source___________SS

apple(1.3)_______139

pear(1.3)________201

pear*apple_______80

apple*apple______48 (non zero!)

pear*pear________3 (small but also non zero)

When setting up the ANOVA calculations I can exclude the apple * apple and pear * pear source, should I? Do I miss something by excluding them.

Comment: Your factors have three levels, 1,2,3.  Did you code as numerical or as a factor? If numerical, interaction of a factor with itself is simply a quadratic term

Comment: numerical, also added into text